# How to combine multiple dataframes with serial numbers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a series of numbered datasets generated from a program, like `data1`, `data2`, ..., `data100`. They have identical column names and I can use `rbind(data1, data2, ...,data100)` to combine them into one dataset. Is there a more efficient way to do it without a loop?

I created a vector of names by `data_names<-paste('data',1:100,sep='')` but the result is a vector of strings. The `rbind(data_names)` command didn't work. Is there a simple and elegant way to combine them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mget` to get all data frames in a list, and then use `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
# Create 3 data frames in the work space as an example
set.seed(1)

data1 <- data.frame(a = runif(2), b = runif(2))
data2 <- data.frame(a = runif(2), b = runif(2))
data3 <- data.frame(a = runif(2), b = runif(2))

# Create the names of the data frame
data_names <- paste0("data", 1:3)

# Get the data frames baed on data_names as a list
data_list <- mget(data_names)

# Combine all data frames using do.call and rbind
data_all <- do.call("rbind", data_list)
```